# player controller in unity 3d not jumping correctly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

i am making a 3d game with a gravity switching mechanic. i have the player walking around the map, and it works on all angles, however the jump is a mess. i was wondering how i could make the jump work.

the jump currently just adds a value to the local up vector. i have no idea how to fix it. i had it working at one point but then i had to switch to physical movement instead of static movement and now it doesn't work.

here is the code:

```cs
void Update()
    {
        //think about moving
        isRunning = (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftControl));
        isShifting = IntToBool((int)((BoolToInt(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftAlt)))*BoolToInt(!isShiftable))+(BoolToInt(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift))*BoolToInt(isShiftable)));

        Vector3 forward = transform.forward;//transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward);
        Vector3 right = transform.right;//transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.right);

        if (((isShifting && isRunning)||!(isShifting && isRunning))) {
            curSpeedX = walkingSpeed*Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
            curSpeedY = walkingSpeed*Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        }
        if (isShifting) {
            curSpeedX = ShiftSpeed*Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
            curSpeedY = ShiftSpeed*Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        }
        if (isRunning) {
            curSpeedX = runningSpeed*Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
            curSpeedY = runningSpeed*Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        }

        //jump
        if (!isGrounded) {
            ypoa -= gravity;
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)) {
            ypoa = jumpheight;
        }
        
        //actualy move
        moveDir = (ypoa*transform.up)+(curSpeedX*transform.forward)+(curSpeedY*transform.right);
        rb.velocity = (moveDir*speed);

        moveDir = new Vector3(0,0,0);
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter() {
        jumcount = 0;
        ypoa = 0;
        isGrounded = true;
    }

    void OnCollisionExit() {
        isGrounded = false;
    }

    void OnCollisionStay() {
        isGrounded = true;
    }
```

i am using unity 2019.4.28f and am on windows 10

help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to move your Physics code into FixedUpdate. If this doesn't work, could you please elaborate more e.g. What happens when you press space?

```
void Update()
    {
        //think about moving
        isRunning = (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftControl));
        isShifting = IntToBool((int)((BoolToInt(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftAlt)))*BoolToInt(!isShiftable))+(BoolToInt(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift))*BoolToInt(isShiftable)));

        Vector3 forward = transform.forward;//transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward);
        Vector3 right = transform.right;//transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.right);

        if (((isShifting && isRunning)||!(isShifting && isRunning))) {
            curSpeedX = walkingSpeed*Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
            curSpeedY = walkingSpeed*Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        }
        if (isShifting) {
            curSpeedX = ShiftSpeed*Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
            curSpeedY = ShiftSpeed*Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        }
        if (isRunning) {
            curSpeedX = runningSpeed*Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
            curSpeedY = runningSpeed*Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        }

        //jump
        if (!isGrounded) {
            ypoa -= gravity;
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)) {
            ypoa = jumpheight;
        }
        
        //actualy move
        moveDir = (ypoa*transform.up)+(curSpeedX*transform.forward)+(curSpeedY*transform.right);
        rb.velocity = (moveDir*speed);

        moveDir = new Vector3(0,0,0);
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter() {
        jumcount = 0;
        ypoa = 0;
        isGrounded = true;
    }

    void OnCollisionExit() {
        isGrounded = false;
    }

    void OnCollisionStay() {
        isGrounded = true;
    }
```